Issue with Update Flow Not Working Across Application on Specific MacBook Pro Machine
I am encountering a peculiar issue with the update flow within our application, specifically on one machine, an Apple MacBook Pro 14 (M3) model. Despite functioning correctly on other devices, including those running Chrome , Edge and Mozilla, the update process consistently fails on this particular machine.
I have verified that all necessary updates and patches are applied to both the application and the operating system. Additionally, I've tested the update functionality across various browsers on different devices without encountering any issues and these devices include MacBook as well, further suggesting that the problem lies with this specific MacBook Pro machine.
Important there is not error showing in the console And It Hit the API Server
Are there any known machine-specific issues, configurations, or compatibility constraints that could be causing this discrepancy? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.
I expected the update flow to function correctly on the MacBook Pro machine, similar to other devices tested, indicating that the issue may be specific to this particular machine.
